# SSH Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) | non-root user

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I have my digitalocean droplets setup so I can login to ssh via keyfiles. This works fine for the root account but if I create a secondary account via `useradd`, the only way I'm able to get into the account is via `su`. If I try to login with ssh using the same keyfile, I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

even though I added my public key to `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`. What to do?

This is a CentOS 7 server.

Note: I also tried adding `AllowUsers exampleuser root` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: Did you restart the `sshd` service and then run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub exampleuser@server` as `exampleuser`? You can also connect with `ssh -vvv` to get more info on what's happening.

Comment: @NasirRiley All I had to do was restart `sshd`. Wasn't thinking about rehashing files. Thanks. If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to restart `sshd` after you've made changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Also note: I had to change file permissions for `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I had was that my key was of **4096** bits size and was not acceptable. I created a **2048** bits key and it worked!

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "<email>"
```

Comment: It works!!! thank you....